# Modal Window Loses Focus when Tab and Shift+Tab is Pressed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm Having a hard time Coding and Trying different approaches on how to catch the tab and Shift+tab when Modal Window is open , It loses focus and Jumps to Text box at the background ,

Can someone Help me with this situation. Thanks

```
 editwindow = $("#modalWindow").kendoWindow({
        title: "Edit Person Information",
        modal: true,
        visible: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 600
    }).data("kendoWindow");
```

Then

```
<div id="modalWindow" class="main">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "People", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PeopleForm" }))
```

Comment: How have you created the modal window?

Comment: @Teemu Question Updated , Added Some parts on Modal Window

Comment: The question is better now : ). Unfortenately I'm not familiar with any techniques you're using on the page... Anyway, there are some possibilities: You can play with [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets), check the `relatedTarget` when [`focusin/out`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusin) fires (unfortenately not available in FF) or "redirect" / prevent tabbig totally in an `keydown` eventhandler.

Comment: @Teemu what about shift+tab, is that handleable ?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, preventing / redirecting `TAB` will work for `SHIFT+TAB` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
$("#modalWindow").kendoWindow({
close: onClose,
**activate: onActivate**
});

function onActivate(e) {
    var windowElement = this.wrapper,
        windowContent = this.element;

    $(document).on("keydown.kendoWindow", function(e) {
        var focusedElement = $(document.activeElement);
        if (e.keyCode == kendo.keys.TAB && focusedElement.closest(windowElement).length == 0) {
            windowContent.focus();
        }
    });
}
```

[Check This](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/window/kendo-window-tab-order-and-section-508.aspx)

Comment: This statement errors `close: onClose`
onClose not identified

Answer (score 0):

I tried other workarounds unsuccessfully.  The solution we're using now follows (this is in our global keydown event handler).  Note - we're ignoring tabindex values here - simply identifying 1st and last :input elements.

```
if (key == kendo.keys.TAB) {
    var $currentOpenWindow = $(".k-window:visible");  // test if there is a window that is currently displayed
    var $inputElements = $currentOpenWindow.find(":input"); // includes buttons
    // if a dialog is currently displayed, don't allow the user to tab out of the dialog into the base form.  Per Casey on 1/2016, we don't need to support nested dialogs.
    if ($currentOpenWindow.length > 0 && $inputElements.length > 0) {
        Utility.log(1, "Enforcing tab within displayed window $currentOpenWindow.length:", $currentOpenWindow.length);
        var isValid = true;
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            if (document.activeElement == $inputElements[0])
                isValid = false;
        }
        else {
            if (document.activeElement == $inputElements[$inputElements.length-1])
                isValid = false;
        }

        if (!isValid) { // Cancel the tab key - this will prevent the browser from changing focus to any other element
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```